# Is it possible to integrate CA SiteMinder with ArcGIS Server 10?

Tags: arcgis-server

I am researching whether or not it is possible and/or desirable to integrate [CA SiteMinder](http://www.ca.com/us/products/detail/ca-siteminder.aspx) with ArcGIS Server 10 in order to restrict access to the various web service endpoints based for authenticated users.

I have googled for whitepapers, solutions, and documentation but every search is coming up blank.

- Has anyone had experience with a CA SiteMinder / ArcGIS Server integration?
- If so, is there any documentation on the integration?

Comment: Whats SiteMinder? Link?

Answer (score 1):

Based upon the limited information I have been able to gleen for CA SiteMinder, it is set up as a portal application. As such provided ArcGIS Server is set up so that the ArcGISSOC and ArcGISSOM accounts and services are allowed to access the data the pointers and cloud service operations of SiteMinder should be fine.

If you can add a little more information on SiteMinder then I could be more specific.

Comment: Based on what I have found so far, I am not sure that the ArcGISSOC and ArcGISSOM accounts will necessarily need to come into play.  CA SiteMinder appears to protect web resources.  Therefore, I should be able to protect http://myarcgisserver.com/arcgis/ and ArcGIS Server should be none the wiser.  The help guide can be found here, note you may need to register with the site in order to read the online help.  https://support.ca.com/cadocs/0/CA%20SiteMinder%20r12%20SP2-ENU/Bookshelf_Files/HTML/index.htm?toc.htm?256306.html

Comment: So Ryan, If I understand the diagram in the link you added you could actually set up a Multi SOM Environment using the CA Load balancer. That is cool for High Avaliability Services. I may get one of our people to look at this further.

Thanks for the info,
CDB

Comment: The diagram reflects SSO across multiple domains and therefore multiple applications in multiple domains. The load balancer appears to be only for the CA SiteMinder Web Agent as the Web Agent must refer to a single cookie provider domain.  If true, it is not used to load balance applications such as ArcGIS Server.  Also, I believe the load balancer is not provided by CA SiteMinder.  I think this can be any load balancer that your organization may already use.  As I learn more I'll continue to update this post.